# How to manage values of a column when some of them have been read in a wrongly?

Tags: r, dplyr, coordinates, data-manipulation, calculated-columns

I am trying to manage a very huge dataframe in which two columns stands for X and Y coordinates. The dataframe have been generated automatically with a software that I have no possibility to manipulate. The problem comes once R read that dataframe and some coords are displayed without the decimal separator, which results in values containing numbers 14-16 character long. The dataframe present the following structure (with no factors):

```
V1  V2           V3
2   41.79905233 12.572052
4   41.7990535  12.57205367
6   4179905383  1257205483
8   4179905433  1257205533
10  41.79905417 12.57205533
12  4179905417  1257205583
```

So, my question is:
How can I to identify values not showing the correct format and how to modify them into the correct one (i.e., two ciphers followed by dec separator 41.245245) taking into account that the number of characters of each cell is not constant?
Consider also that the distribution of values along the columns does not show any pattern.

Thank you in advance.

I tried these codes with dplyr without success... even remotely

```
df %>%
  mutate(df$V4 == ifelse(V2 > 100, V2/100000000, V2 == V2))

df %>%
    mutate(df$V4 = ifelse(V2, function(x) as.numeric(x)[1] > 100, 
                        map_dbl(V4, function(x) as.numeric(x)[1] / 100000000),
                        V4))
```

Comment: Why all the tidyverse code?  Pick a column, search for values > 100, stringify them, insert a "." after the first 2 chars, and apply `as.numeric` .

Comment: Thank you Carl for your suggestion! I've tried but since I am a new user in R I am just following already coded strings. Could you please, type down the code? Thank you..

Comment: If the correct Y coordinates are ever <10, how would we know? Are you sure they're always two digits?

Comment: Your code is close, you could use `df %>% mutate(V4 = V2 / ifelse(V2 > 100, 1E8, 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the coordinates are always supposed to be between 10 and 99.999, you could use some math to keep the output in that range without a departure into strings:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(V2:V3, ~.x / 10^(floor(log10(.x))-1)))

  V1       V2       V3
1  2 41.79905 12.57205
2  4 41.79905 12.57205
3  6 41.79905 12.57205
4  8 41.79905 12.57206
5 10 41.79905 12.57206
6 12 41.79905 12.57206
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in a `dplyr` chain you can do something like this, which also employs @Carl Witthoft's suggestion of turning it into a character and subbing in a `.`

With a reprex of your example, that would look like this:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(2,4,6,8),
  V2 = c(41.79905233,41.7990535,4179905383,4179905433),
  V3 = c(12.572052,12.57205367,1257205483,1257205533)
)

df_fixed <- df %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    # use if else
    V2 = ifelse(
      # if value is over 100,
      V2 > 100, 
      # use gsub here to put the decimal after the second place in the string
      # then convert the result back to a numeric
      as.numeric(gsub('^(.{2})(.*)$', '\\1.\\2', as.character(V2))),
      # if the value isn't over 100, leave as is
      V2),
    V3 = ifelse(V3 > 100, 
                as.numeric(gsub('^(.{2})(.*)$', '\\1.\\2', as.character(V3))),
                V3)
  )
```

Though note here, that in the `gsub(..)`, the number in the curly braces (in this example it's `{2}` is the position *after* which the decimal is added. So if you have locations that are also in other parts of the globe, your longitudinal values could be both 12.5 or 125.1 (you will know if your data include both) so you'd need to change the mutation of `V3` variable and it would be more complicated. But if you know that's not the case, you're all good.

This all gives you a result that looks like this:

```
     V1    V2    V3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2  41.8  12.6
2     4  41.8  12.6
3     6  41.8  12.6
4     8  41.8  12.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for the comments! You three were right about the coordinates, there were other coordinates from other parts of the globe, differently as I noticed at the begining. Anyway I manage to solve it combining all the suggestions, so thank you all.
The code that worked best was this one with modifications as coordinates required depending on where were located (which obviously needed to know the dataset)

```
df_fixed <- df %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    # use if else
    V2 = ifelse(
      # if value is over 100,
      V2 > 100, 
      # use gsub here to put the decimal after the second place in the string
      # then convert the result back to a numeric
      as.numeric(gsub('^(.{2})(.*)$', '\\1.\\2', as.character(V2))),
      # if the value isn't over 100, leave as is
      V2),
    V3 = ifelse(V3 > 100, 
                as.numeric(gsub('^(.{2})(.*)$', '\\1.\\2', as.character(V3))),
                V3)
  )
```

However, I also used this suggestion when calculations were a more inmediate operation:

```
df %>%
 mutate(across(V2:V3, ~.x / 10^(floor(log10(.x))-1)))
```

Cheers!
Carlos